# Rails "automatic" routes don't work, must specify with get "controller/method" every time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I did

`rails generate controller home index`

But it adds this line to my routes.rb

`get "home/index"`

I thought Rails could deduce controller/method from the URL automatically? Why do I need to specify every get/post page?

Here's my complete routes.rb file:

```
Callisto2::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "home#index"
  resources :assets
end
```

root "/" works fine. so does /assets/*.

What's the problem with /home/index? I get the error:

**Routing Error**

`No route matches [GET] "/home/index"`

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

`rake routes` (run as apache user) gives me the following output:

```
root  / home#index
```

Thanks for any clarifications. Not sure what I'm missing.

Edit: I didn't make this clear: I manually removed get /home/index from routes.rb to keep that file clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails used to add the so called catch all route at the bottom of your routes file:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

There was nothing 'automatic' or magical about these urls, just that every rails app started out with this route in their routes.rb

This has fallen out of favour, at least partially because it makes everything accessible over get, whereas

```
resources :books
```

Adds each route with the appropriate http verb. Listing routes explicitly is also a lot less verbose than when rails started out.

Comment: so rail generate should have added 'resources home' to my routes, but since that exposes everything (i.e. every future method that may not be intended to be rout-able like 'home/doX' will be available)

Comment: If you scaffold a model rails adds the resourceful routes. If not it doesn't make any assumptions about what you are doing and just sets up the routes for the actions you pass to the generator

Answer (score 1):

If your controller is `home` and the action is `index` your path is just `/home`.

You can find more information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

Comment: noob here, yep I understand now. Due to my past experience I expected /home/ to call the index method, but it actually calls /home/show?id=index , which doesn't exist. I found this out after manually adding resources :home to route.rb